# Need a way to make the loop faster in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I work for a construction company. I have been writing a macro for the inventory department which can retrieve the latest date on which a particular type of material was supplied to a specific Flat No. at site.

The code which I have is doing the job but it's taking very long to compute all the results. Can anyone tell me how to make this go even faster.

Following is the code:

```
Sub FillTopSheet()
'Designing a loop to move through the fill data on Top Sheet
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Declaring variables for counts
Dim Flat_Row_Num As Long
Dim Tower_Col_Num As Long
Dim InventoryWs As Worksheet

'Debug.Print Application.Workbooks("The Crest DLF Project-In-Out Inventory Data.xlsx").Worksheets("Material-Out").Name
Set InventoryWs = Application.Workbooks("The Crest DLF Project-In-Out Inventory Data.xlsx").Worksheets("Material-Out")

Dim Lookup_Start_Row As Long
Dim Lookup_End_Row As Long

'Lookup_Start_Row = 4
'
'Select Case Application.ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Name
'    Case "Kitchen Carcass"
'        Do Until InventoryWs.Cells(Lookup_Start_Row, 2).Value = "Kitchen Carcass"
'                Lookup_Start_Row = Lookup_Start_Row + 1
'        Loop
'
'        Lookup_End_Row = Lookup_Start_Row
'
'        Do While InventoryWs.Cells(Lookup_End_Row, 2).Value = "Kitchen Carcass"
'        Lookup_End_Row = Lookup_End_Row + 1
'
'        Loop
'
'        Lookup_End_Row = Lookup_End_Row - 1
'
'End Select

Debug.Print Lookup_Start_Row
Debug.Print Lookup_End_Row
Lookup_Start_Row = 6162
Lookup_End_Row = 14754

Flat_Row_Num = 5
Tower_Col_Num = 5

Do Until Tower_Col_Num > 13

    Do Until Flat_Row_Num > 154
        If Application.ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(Flat_Row_Num, Tower_Col_Num - 1).Value <> "" Then
            Do Until Lookup_Start_Row = Lookup_End_Row
                If Application.ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(Flat_Row_Num, Tower_Col_Num - 1).Value = _
                InventoryWs.Cells(Lookup_Start_Row, 8).Value Then
                    Application.ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(Flat_Row_Num, Tower_Col_Num).Value = _
                    InventoryWs.Cells(Lookup_Start_Row, 6).Value
                    GoTo RowReset
                Else
                    Application.ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(Flat_Row_Num, Tower_Col_Num).Value = "NA"
                End If

                Lookup_Start_Row = Lookup_Start_Row + 1
            Loop
            Lookup_Start_Row = 6162
RowReset:
Lookup_Start_Row = 6162
        End If
        Flat_Row_Num = Flat_Row_Num + 1
    Loop
Flat_Row_Num = 5
Tower_Col_Num = Tower_Col_Num + 2
Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```

Comment: Finding it hard to see what you're code's trying to do.  You have a lot of verbose code in there - `Application.ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet...`.  You don't need `Application.ThisWorkbook` - `ThisWorkbook` always refers to the workbook containing the code, which will always be in the Excel Application.  `ActiveSheet` may not be in `ThisWorkbook` and you don't explicitly set any worksheet to be active so it could be the wrong sheet.  What's your code meant to be doing?  Have you tried using [FIND](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-find-method-excel) instead?

Comment: "retrieve the latest date on which a particular type of material was supplied to a specific Flat No." seems very doable through simple formula. Example: https://exceljet.net/formula/maximum-if-multiple-criteria

Comment: I have all the Flat Nos. on a workbook against which I need to retrieve a date which is the latest delivery date for that Flat. I have an Inventory Workbook which records all the materials delivered within a period. One flat can receive material numerous times so it will have duplicates. I have sorted the Data First by Flat No. and Second By Newest Date. This loop is comparing one Flat No. with all cell the Flat Nos. in the Inventory Master and obviously taking a lot of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could be something like this but indexes (i,j,k) might be mixed up.
Would be much easier if you could post your input and desired output (eg some screenshot)

```
Sub FillTopSheet()

    'Declaring variables for counts
    Dim Flat_Row_Num As Long
    Dim Tower_Col_Num As Long
    Dim InventoryWs As Worksheet, Ws As Worksheet
    Dim ArrLookUp() As Variant, ArrData() As Variant
    Dim Lookup_Start_Row As Long, Lookup_End_Row As Long, i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
    Dim FlatNo As String

    'Designing a loop to move through the fill data on Top Sheet
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    'Debug.Print Application.Workbooks("The Crest DLF Project-In-Out Inventory Data.xlsx").Worksheets("Material-Out").Name
    Set InventoryWs = Application.Workbooks("The Crest DLF Project-In-Out Inventory Data.xlsx").Worksheets("Material-Out")

    Debug.Print Lookup_Start_Row
    Debug.Print Lookup_End_Row

    Lookup_Start_Row = 6162
    Lookup_End_Row = 14754

    Flat_Row_Num = 5
    Tower_Col_Num = 2 'Start in Tower A "Flats No. column

    With InventoryWs
        ArrLookUp = .Range(.Cells(Lookup_Start_Row, 6), .Cells(Lookup_End_Row, 8))
    End With

    With Ws
        ArrData = .Range(.Cells(Flat_Row_Num, Tower_Col_Num), .Cells(154, 13))
    End With

    For i = LBound(ArrData, 2) To UBound(ArrData, 2) Step 2
        For j = LBound(ArrData) To UBound(ArrData)
            'loop through "towers" Array
            FlatNo = ArrData(j, i) 'take one flat no
            If FlatNo <> "" Then
                For k = LBound(ArrLookUp) To UBound(ArrLookUp)
                    'look for this flat no in other array
                    If FlatNo = ArrLookUp(k, 3) Then
                        'first match = take Date from other array
                        'dates sorted descending
                        ArrData(j, i + 1) = ArrLookUp(k, 1)
                        'found what was looking for, get out of loop
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next k
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

    With Ws
        'range must be same as when you set the array earlier. But if that range contains some formulas they'll be overwriten with values
        'in that case you can loop through array and take out only dates
        .Range(.Cells(Flat_Row_Num, Tower_Col_Num), .Cells(154, 13)) = ArrData
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

Edit
 
This still might need some adjustment to fit in your ranges 
 
Check ranges in `ArrLookUp = .Range(.Cells(Lookup_Start_Row, 6), .Cells(Lookup_End_Row, 8))` and `ArrLookUp = .Range(.Cells(Lookup_Start_Row, 6), .Cells(Lookup_End_Row, 8))`

It takes "Towers" and looks for "Flats No." in other sheet. At first match date is taken from other sheet.

Comment: Following is the link for snapshot of my main report:  [link]https://photos.app.goo.gl/uTXGedtrYtGELsDj7  and Following is the link for the snapshot of Inventory Records Workbooks  [link]https://photos.app.goo.gl/KHaaQ9HnKUTtnuMN7